# how to know if the data-binding source/path works

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF data-binding. I wrote a small program for data-binding test. There are 2 windows.
In Window1.xaml.cs,

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string test = "aaa";
    string Test
    {
        get { return test; }
        set { test = value; }
    }
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Window1 W1 = new Window1();
        textBlock.DataContext = this;//data-binding source
        textBlock1.DataContext = W1;//data-binding source
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int a;
    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        a++; //why does not it update the value in the UI?
    }
}
```

And finally in MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Button x:Name="button" Click="button_Click"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding A}"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Test}"/> //Why does not it work?
```

I want to update the MainWindow UI when I click the button, as well as binding a string type value "aaa" from another window. But I don't know where goes wrong. I also don't know if there is a way to check if the binding source and path are valid. Thanks.

Comment: It has to be `public` property.

Comment: First in the `button_Click` method you are increasing the field, while you should increase the property. Second, you should invoke the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `A` property

Comment: Oh yes, my carelessness, thanks. @Sinatr

Comment: OK, thank you. I got it. I will search for that. @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix these 2 problems. As Sinatr and Alex mentioned,

Firstly,

```
public string Test
{
    get { return test; }
    set { test = value; }
}
```

Secondly,

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    a++; //why does not it update the value in the UI?
    OnPropertyChanged("A");
}
```